# Simplifying the sum $\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n} t(t+1)v^t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

For the sum:
$$\sum_{t=1}^{n} t(t+1)v^t,$$
would there be a "simple" formula for this? Such as:
$$S=\sum_{t=1}^{n} tv^t = \frac{\frac{1-v^n}{1-v} - n v^n}{\frac{1}{v} - 1}$$?
(The second sum is the present value of an annuity increasing by \$1 every period, for anyone curious).
I understand that it'll boil down to simplifying the sum to
$$\sum_{t=1}^{n}t^2v^t + S $$
but I'm not sure if there's a nice formula for the first part.

Comment: Hint: $$\sum_{t=1}^nt^2v^t=v\frac{dS}{dv}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I haven't tried much because I couldn't think of any neat way to approach it. I did try manipulating the sum by subtracting multiples of itself but that didn't work.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks. I'm not sure what to do with that right now but does it have something to do with integrals (riemann sum)?  
Edit: nvm, I think I found the prpose of the hint

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours :-) It's a nifty ole derivative.

Comment: Thank you @SimplyBeautifulArt , I really liked the use of the derivative there. Just one operation on an already known result and we get the formula.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $S_n=\sum_{t=1}^n t(t+1)x^t$. Then
$$(1-x)S_n=\sum_{t=1}^n \left[t(t+1)-(t-1)t\right]x^t-n(n+1)x^{n+1}
=2\sum_{t=1}^ntx^t-n(n+1)x^{n+1}.$$
So if you can work  out $\sum_{t=1}^ntx^t$ you can find $S_n$.

Comment: Hm, oddly, I give my first upvote to you.  :-P (haven't seen much of your work yet)  (always love those algebraic solutions)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt You haven't seen much of his work because he is Lord Shark the **Unknown**, obviously

Comment: Why does your first sum involve $x^{\color{red} {n}} $ but your second sum does not?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**:

Let

$$S_n(v)=\sum_{t=1}^n v^t=v\frac{1-v^n}{1-v}.$$

Then

$$v^2S_n'(v)=\sum_{t=1}^n tv^{t+1}$$

and

$$(v^2S_n'
(v))'=2vs_n'(v)+v^2S_n''(v)=\sum_{t=1}^n t(t+1)v^t.$$

---

For convenient computation, you can differentiate $(1-v)S_n(v)$ twice, giving $$(1-v)S_n'(v)-S_n(v)$$ and $$(1-v)S_n''(v)-2S_n'(v).$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S = \sum_{t = 1}^{n} t^2 v^t$

$S =  v + 4v^2 + 9v^3 + ... + n^2 v^n$

$Sv = \ \ \ \ \ v^2 +  4v^3 + ... + n^2 v^{n+1}$

$S(1-v) = v + 3v^2 + 5v^3 + ... (n^2 - (n-1)^2)v^n - n^2 v^{n+1}$

$S(1-v)v = \ \ \ \ \ v^2 + 3v^3 + ... ((n-1)^2 - (n-2)^2)v^n + (n^2 - (n-1)^2)v^{n+1} - n^2 v^{n+2}$

$S(1-v)^2 = v + 2v^2 + 2v^3 + ... 2v^n - (n^2 + 2n - 1)v^{n+1} + n^2 v^{n+2}$

$S(1-v)^2 = v + 2v^2(1 + v + v^2 + ... v^{n-2}) - (n^2 + 2n - 1)v^{n+1} + n^2 v^{n+2}$

$S = \frac{v}{(1-v)^2} - \frac{2v^2 (v^{n-1} - 1)}{(1-v)^3} - \frac{(n^2 + 2n -1 )v^{n+1}}{(1-v)^2} + \frac{n^2v^{n+2}}{(1-v)^2}$

EDIT: This can be further simplified to:

$S = -\frac{n^2v^{n+1}}{(1-v)} - \frac{2nv^{n+1}}{(1-v)^2} + \frac{v(1-v^n)(1+v)}{(1-v)^3}$

Verify: $n = 0$, gives $S = 0$

$n = 1$; $S = -\frac{v^2}{(1-v)} - \frac{2v^2}{(1-v)^2} + \frac{v(1-v)(1+v)}{(1-v)^3} = v$